# como puedo agregar una etiqueta img a un button con Create Element?

Tags: javascript, dom, createjs

```
const buttonAdd = document.createElement('button').textContent = 'Add to cart';
buttonAdd.classList ='primary-button add-to-cart-button';
```

este es el botton

```
const imgButtonCar = document.createElement('img');
imgButtonCar.setAttribute('src', './icons/bt_add_to_cart.svg');
```

esta es la imagen que quiero colocar dentro del boton.
El asunto es que no me renderiza los elementos de mi carrito de compras y me aparece el siguiente error en consola **Uncaught TypeError: buttonAdd.appendChild is not a function**, cuando agrego la img al button con append child, es raro porque ya lo habia echo en html y me lo renderisava perfectamente, espero me puedan apoyar con una solucion. Gracias colegas!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en como estás haciendo la asignación acá:

```
const buttonAdd = document.createElement('button').textContent = 'Add to cart';
```

Podemos hacer una ley asociativa en esta asignación para que veas el problema:

```
const buttonAdd = (document.createElement('button').textContent = 'Add to cart');
const buttonAdd = ('Add to cart') // ahora buttonAdd es un 'string'
```

Tienes que tener cuidado con este tipo de asignaciones, como `buttonAdd` es un string, un string no tiene el método `appendChild`.

---

En vez de esto deberías asignar `buttonAdd` de esta forma:

```
const buttonAdd = document.createElement('button'); // Asi buttonAdd es ahora un HTMLElement que si contiene 'appendChild'
buttonAdd.textContent = 'Add to cart';
buttonAdd.classList = 'primary-button add-to-cart-button';
```